Getting the body of a POST request in a Blazor component
There is a lot of information online about reading query strings in Blazor. This involves using the GET method. But what if I need to get data not from the query string, but from the body of the request sent by the POST method to the address of the Blazor component? How can you get the request body in this case for further work with it?

Do you mean making an HTTP POST request from Blazor using HTTPClient?

Below is the code for a Blazor component making a POST request.
/* Assume this is the submit/login button 
EditForm Model=@Model OnSubmit="LoginUser">
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
*/

private async Task LoginUser()
{
            var model = new
        {
            username = "user1",
            password = "password134"
        };

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress  = new Uri("https://localhost:9000");
        var res = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/account", model);

        // deserialize, convert res to LoginResponseModel
        loggedInUser = await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<LoginResponseModel>();

        Console.WriteLine($"token: {loggedInUser.Token}");

}


...but from the body of the request sent by the POST method to the address of the Blazor component...

I don't get your comment, what's your doubt? It will make an HTTP POST request to the URL mentioned localhost:9000 here, change it if you want, and send the username and pwd in the request body. You can assign the username and password to the inputs in the login form.
